# SQL Server Loop and Cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have inherited the following code for SQL Server:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE 
@PERSON_ID AS INT, 
@COMMS_DATE AS DATE,
@PERSON_ID_HOLD AS INT, 
@COMMS_DATE_HOLD AS DATE,
@CAMPAIGN_ID AS INT,
@CAMPAIGN_ID_OLD AS INT,
@SQL AS VARCHAR(200)

SELECT @PERSON_ID_HOLD = 0
SELECT @COMMS_DATE_HOLD = null
SELECT @CAMPAIGN_ID = 0
SELECT @CAMPAIGN_ID_OLD = 0

DECLARE COMMS_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
SELECT PERSONID, ReportDate FROM ##Motability_Comms_Combined order by PersonID, ReportDate

OPEN COMMS_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM COMMS_CURSOR
INTO @PERSON_ID, @COMMS_DATE

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
IF (@PERSON_ID = @PERSON_ID_HOLD) and (DATEDIFF(day,@COMMS_DATE_HOLD,@COMMS_DATE) > 90)
BEGIN
IF @CAMPAIGN_ID = 0
begin
SET @PERSON_ID_HOLD = @PERSON_ID
SET @COMMS_DATE_HOLD = @COMMS_DATE
end
ELSE
begin 
SET @CAMPAIGN_ID_OLD = @CAMPAIGN_ID
SET @CAMPAIGN_ID = @CAMPAIGN_ID + 1
END
end
ELSE

IF (@PERSON_ID <> @PERSON_ID_HOLD)-- or (@COMMS_DATE <> @COMMS_DATE_HOLD)
BEGIN
SET @CAMPAIGN_ID = 1
SET @CAMPAIGN_ID_OLD = @CAMPAIGN_ID
END

IF (@CAMPAIGN_ID > 1)
BEGIN
UPDATE ##Motability_Comms_Combined SET Derived_Campaign_ID = @CAMPAIGN_ID WHERE personid = @PERSON_ID AND REPORTDATE = @COMMS_DATE  --WHERE CURRENT OF COMMS_CURSOR
END

SET @PERSON_ID_HOLD = @PERSON_ID
SET @COMMS_DATE_HOLD = @COMMS_DATE
FETCH NEXT FROM COMMS_CURSOR INTO @PERSON_ID, @COMMS_DATE
END

CLOSE COMMS_Cursor
DEALLOCATE COMMS_Cursor

UPDATE ##Motability_Comms_Combined SET Derived_Campaign_ID = 1 WHERE Derived_Campaign_ID is null

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Please can anybody tell me what the purpose of this kind of SQL is e.g. nocount, declare, cursors, while etc? Is there another way of doing it with selects instead?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Do you even try use Google or read manual?

Comment: Maybe try and ask a more specific question

Comment: Thanks lad2025. Do you ever try learn English?

Comment: More specifically, what is the purpose of opening a cursor(?) and looping through in sql and adding one to a row and then use set each time? Could you use a case statement instead? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- SET NOCOUNT ON will prevent a message being returned saying how many rows were updated. In some situations in code this is necessary because the message is interpreted as an additional resultset. There is also some additional overhead with this message.
- CURSORS are used to perform operations in a procedural fashion instead of the usual set based fashion (for instance if you need to loop through some data executing a stored procedure for every row). They are quite resource-intensive and usually frowned upon. It appears that this could be re-written without a cursor.
- "##Motability_Comms_Combined is a global temporary table, so may also be referred to by other code (in a different SQL connection)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In SQL Server Management Studio do you know if there is a way to step through each step of the loop to see the output?

Comment: Or is there a standard method instead of using cursors?

Comment: You can right click on a stored proc in management studio and select execute. You can put break points in the stored procedure to stop, and examine variables etc.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help.